# Changing the ON condition order results in different query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Will there be any difference if I change the order from this to the next one in the last line ESPECIALLY when I use left join or left outer join? SOme people confuse me that it might have differnet value when we change order, I reckon they themselves aren't sure about this.

Or, if we change the order, under what situations such as right outer, right, left, left outer joins the query result differs?

Comment: Your queries are syntactically incorrect, so it is very hard to tell what you want to do.  Why isn't `PB` defined in the `from` clause?  Your question is about joins, but your query doesn't have any.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Haha, I know, but just had a doubt, so quickly took extract from my big SP...Anyway, no worries, but the question here is, just making columns right or left side to equal makes any difference in result

Comment: Why do you have `NOLOCK`?

Comment: @wewesthemenace: I like your name.... Don't know why we have; but in my team everyone are used to using this while doing any queries. even during every join table, they write NOLOCK, don't see a point though personally, but I am junior in my team

Comment: @Divine Using `NOLOCK` have some side effects. Read on this article for reference: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @wewesthemenace: Thank you for sharing this, I am reading this link now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference which side you put criteria on when an `=` is being used.

Table order matters in the case of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, but criteria order does not.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
 ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 a
RIGHT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.ID = b.ID
```

But not equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cf879/5/0)

Comment: sorry, I am not talking about results ordering, but query framing i.e. order of columns keeping it right or left would result in different results? Consider all scenarios such as left, right, left outer etc etc

Comment: What do you mean by table order, could you pls explain with a small example of how I can see difference in results?

Comment: Goat, thank you, now I realize the difference in results for changing table order, however, I couldn't understand why 1st query result is different from 3rd query. I mean, I am trying to understand how it executes behind the scene, is there a notes to read it and understand? I mean, first which query executes and then what happens etc?

Comment: `LEFT` and `RIGHT` indicate which side of the join will bring back records regardless of whether or not they join to the other table.  So `Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2` will bring back all records from `Table1`.  `Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1` will bring back all records from `Table2`.    Here's a handy reference: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
It doesn't include `RIGHT` but it should help still.

Comment: Goat, thank you so much, I am happy I understood it now :) I will also read the link you gave for indepth insights